# Jenkins docker does not create InitialAdminPassword when launched from ansible

Tags: docker, jenkins, installation, ansible

I've been writing an ansible script to spawn a Jenkins docker container and am running into some trouble. Here's the snippet that downloads and runs the container:

```
  - name: Get the jenkins docker image.
    docker_image:
      name: jenkins/jenkins
      source: pull
  - name: Run the jenkins docker image.
    docker_container:
      image: jenkins/jenkins
      name: jenkins
      ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
      restart_policy: always
      state: started
      volumes:
      - /jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

Note that I've tried both `jenkins/jenkins:latest` and `jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11` in my script. Same result.

When I run my playbook, the image is pulled and the container is launched. However, when I go to run `docker exec jenkins cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`, the file does not exist. I also check the logs with `docker logs jenkins`, expecting to see the password in there as well, but I get:

```
2021-06-06 12:58:42.994+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2021-06-06 12:58:43.123+0000 [id=42]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-06-06 12:58:45.623+0000 [id=53]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
```

Wondering if this is the culprit, but am not sure.

If I comment out the `docker_container` step and run the container from the command line, it works:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins -d jenkins/jenkins
```

When I check out the docker logs, the WARNING message I'd previously seen is not there and I see that admin password in the logs as well. My conclusion at this point is that I've omitted something in my ansible script, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can run as a root user with `-u` option with `0` value .This will run as a root user (uid=0)

```
docker run -u 0 -d -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins -d jenkins/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

... and of course, all it took was to ask the question.

The problem appears to have been the permissions on my volume (`/jenkins`); when the container is started, jenkins is unable to write to it if the directory has not been created with the appropriate permissions.

Hope this helps someone out there.